# Algorithm: Find the minimum number of sets containing your entire domain

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given few sets and a number n:

```
Here assume n is 5:
a - (0,1,2)
b - (0,1,2,3)
c - (1,3,4,5)
d - (0,1,2,4)
e - (2,3,4,5)
f - (3,5)
```

Now if we take just `b` and `c` we get the entire range from 0 to 5.

I was thinking of a greedy approach but that does not seems to fit here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) and, as such, NP-complete, meaning you have to consider every possible solution and choose the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to get minimum number of sets if easy to get by checking all the possible subsets , but this will take `2^k` when `k` is the number of sets.

You can do it by building graph  and run DFS with depth of 1,2,3 ... till you get full coverage.

There is a trade of between run time and the optimal solution. is will accept not the min sets than there are option with less run time

Comment: `K^2` is wrong, there might be more than 2 sets needed to cover the whole set.

Answer (score 0):

A BFS search can easily solve this problem.

```
min = 0

function bfs(i, visited sets)
    if i > m
        n = the number of the visited sets without duplicates
        if n < min
            min = n
        end
        return
    end

    if no set contains i
        return
    end

    for each set that contains i
        bfs(i+1, visited sets + this set)
    end
end
```

Start searching from i = 0 and empty visited sets

```
bfs(0, empty set)
```

Then the `min` will be the minimum number of sets.

Comment: can you think about complexity of this problem ? How is it better ?

Comment: Well, I think the complexity is O(N^m), where N is the number of the sets.

Comment: Each function makes potentially `N` recursive calls; `N` sets are potentially required to construct the answer, thus the complexity is `O(N^N)`.

Comment: @ring0 I just meant it is not better then the first answer